# Mod4-Space does nothing

Tags: awesome-wm

I am running awesome 3.4.15 (Never Gonna Give You Up), and most of the hotkeys seem to work fine, including Mod4-j, Mod4-enter, Mod4-r, Mod4-x.

However, Mod4-Space does nothing. The window tiles do not change, and the layout does not seem to either, as indicted by the layout icon in the upper right corner of the screen not changing. If I click on the layout icon, the layout does change, however.

Comment: Hello, just a note. v3.4 is 8 years old and unsupported since 2012 (5 years ago). It has many issues that are never going to get fixed, ever. While this is not one of them (my guest is that your windows/clients are floating or maximized). Before you waste time on this, consider upgrading to a supported version. The currently supported release is 4.x (4.2, as of today).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Not sure why my install is so old since I've only had the computer a year, but I will try to upgrade.